# iPad app, will run in debug but adhoc crashes

Tags: ipad, ios, adhoc, sigabrt

Here is the crash log

```
Date/Time:       2011-02-10 21:12:00.478 +0900
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.2.1 (8C148)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d7c2d4 __kill + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d7c2c4 kill + 4
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d7c2b6 raise + 10
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x30d90d72 abort + 50
4   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x34981a20 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 376
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34a83594 _objc_terminate + 104
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3497fdf2 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 46
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3497fe46 std::terminate() + 10
8   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3497ff16 __cxa_throw + 78
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34a824c4 objc_exception_throw + 64
10  CoreFoundation                  0x3587c1a8 +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 96
11  CoreFoundation                  0x35823aa2 ___forwarding___ + 502
12  CoreFoundation                  0x35823858 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 40
13  PictureDictionary               0x00005fe4 sgLoadFileImage(char const*, long*) (PictureDictionary.mm:41)
14  PictureDictionary               0x000061b0 CPictureDictionary::LoadPageData() (PictureDictionary.mm:814)
15  PictureDictionary               0x00006d02 CPictureDictionary::Update() (PictureDictionary.mm:505)
16  PictureDictionary               0x00003216 -[ES1Renderer render] (ES1Renderer.mm:63)
```

The line in my code where it starts to crash (with in stack trash #13 above) is

> NSString* pStr = [[NSString alloc]
>   initWithUTF8String: pFileName];

For some reason it crashes here.
What is odd is that it runs fine in debug mode. But when I make a adhoc build and put it in the iPad through iTunes the above crash occurs.

I have cleaned and rebuilt many times, made sure my profiles and identifiers are correct.
I have no idea why this may be happening. Any insight or suggestions will help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry I'm no guru but maybe this will help a little.

This type of crash occurs when Cocoa cannot find the method you are invoking at runtime.

Normally you would receive a warning during compilation.

That said, it seems to be complaining that it cannot find an objective-C selector (method). However, sgLoadFileImage looks to me to be a C function.

For sure, something is different between your debug and release builds. Either the code is different, or the parameters supplied to the methods and functions.

Comment: Thanks, I still dont know what it was, but I deleted my adhoc build setting, copied my debug build setting and just changed the profile and that fixed it. I guess i must of changed something and didnt notice.

Comment: I had no idea either, but I just started from scratch with that BUILD configuration and it worked for me too

Comment: @funckymonk My AdHoc configuration is a clone of RELEASE, _not_ DEBUG. (My AppStore configuration _is_ a clone if RELEASE). I wonder why you do different. In any case, my app is crashing in AdHoc but not when running the RELEASE config from Xcode... Weird? Crash log is EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV).

Comment: Now it's working... changed a couple of **strong** NSString properties to 'copy'. Guess it makes a huge difference when there is no debugger attached and the code is optimized...